# Form submission error message implementation

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, typescript, angular-material

I need to display simple error messages in my Angular Material app, mostly in cases when form submission fails.

Material specification has [guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors) for `Errors detected upon form submission`.

All I can google on the built-in ways to show errors in Angular Material is `<mat-error>` displayed by form fields when validation fails. But suppose we need to display errors in situations not related to form fields. Maybe we've got an error from the back-end as a result of incorrectly typed user/password or something else.

Is there a specific component built-in Angular Material framework or we need to implement it by our self? If latter is the case, what should be the implementation including styling (font and size, colors, etc.)?

This is the very common piece of code required by almost every app and I think it would be nice if we work out a decent component for the case Angular Material still doesn't have it.

Comment: Have you seen the section on app errors in the guidelines? https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/errors.html#errors-app-errors.

Comment: So let me try to understand, you found the guidelines related to errors and despite the fact that there are a tone of examples showing that the common approach is to either show a dialog, snackbar or an error state view you still need to make a question? Check the material.io site and look for elements similar to the ones on the examples of the guidelines...

Comment: @Jota.Toledo: No. First of all, I just need to display simple error messages in my app, mostly when form submission fails. That's the motivation. Now, I'm wondering if Angular Material has built-in component (which probably implements Material guidelines) as it has for form field errors or it gotta be implemented from scratch. See my updated question.

Comment: @serpent5: Yes, that link is already there in my updated answer. But I'm looking for some implementation which conforms to the guidelines, not the guidelines themselves.